# C# - Convert String array to String List

Tags: c#

```
string[] val_1;

List<string> val_2;
```

I'm trying to convert `string` array to `string` list. I need an effective way.

Both should be in `string` list format to compare both.

Comment: val_2 = val_1.ToList()

Comment: _"Both should be in string List format to compare both"_ Why you can't compare a list with an array? For example: `val_1.SequenceEqual(val_2)`.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar that specific question is about an Array object, but it still definitely is a duplicate.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thank you it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

**Using LINQ `ToList()`** extension method - add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your source file and then do:

```
var list = array.ToList();
```

Second option is to directly initialize the list **via the constructor**:

```
var list = new List<string>(array);
```

There is no difference in performance between these two approaches, both will take linear time relative to the number of items in the array (`O(N)`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Linq`'s ToList method:

```
val_2 = val_1.ToList();
```

Make sure `val_1` is initialized though!